# Pantalla de AVD muy pequeña, lo curioso es que la parte negra responde y lo marca en la pantalla pequeña

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, avd

La pantalla del AVD esta muy pequeña y la parte negra responde a los clicks.
[image: pantalla pequeña en AVD]

Answer (score 0):

seguramente al crear el dispositivo, configuraste mal la resolución, te sugiero que en la columna "Actions" clickes en el desplegable y selecciones la opción "Edit" y desde ahí cambies la resolución a una que te permita trabajar mejor.

[image: Resolución]

[image: Lista de dispositivos]

[image: Configuración del dispositivo]